# Fixed sidebar scroll, prevent pushing footer down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make a fixed sidebar scroll along side the viewport along with you here is a working example

**[Codepen](http://codepen.io/noobskie/pen/NNvwNe?editors=1010)**

```js
$(function() {

    var $sidebar   = $("#sidebar"), 
        $window    = $(window),
        offset     = $sidebar.offset(),
        topPadding = 15;

    $window.scroll(function() {
        if ($window.scrollTop() > offset.top) {
            $sidebar.stop().animate({
                marginTop: $window.scrollTop() - offset.top + topPadding
            });
        } else {
            $sidebar.stop().animate({
                marginTop: 0
            });
        }
    });
    
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.container -->
</nav>
<!-- /.navbar -->

<div class="container">

  <div class="row row-offcanvas row-offcanvas-right">

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9">
      <p class="pull-right visible-xs">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-toggle="offcanvas">Toggle nav</button>
      </p>
      <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
        <p>This is an example to show the potential of an offcanvas layout pattern in Bootstrap. Try some responsive-range viewport sizes to see it in action.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-lg-4">
          <h2>Heading</h2>
          <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
        </div>
        <!--/.col-xs-6.col-lg-4-->
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-lg-4">
          <h2>Heading</h2>
          <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
        </div>
        <!--/.col-xs-6.col-lg-4-->
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-lg-4">
          <h2>Heading</h2>
          <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
        </div>
        <!--/.col-xs-6.col-lg-4-->
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-lg-4">
          <h2>Heading</h2>
          <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
        </div>
        <!--/.col-xs-6.col-lg-4-->
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-lg-4">
          <h2>Heading</h2>
          <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
        </div>
        <!--/.col-xs-6.col-lg-4-->
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-lg-4">
          <h2>Heading</h2>
          <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
        </div>
        <!--/.col-xs-6.col-lg-4-->
      </div>
      <!--/row-->
    </div>
    <!--/.col-xs-12.col-sm-9-->

    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 sidebar-offcanvas" id="sidebar">
      <div class="list-group">
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item active">Link</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Link</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Link</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Link</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Link</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Link</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Link</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Link</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Link</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Link</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--/.sidebar-offcanvas-->
  </div>
  <!--/row-->

  <hr>

  <footer>
    <p>&copy; 2015 Company, Inc.</p>
  </footer>

</div>
<!--/.container-->
```

Here is the code in question

```
$(function() {

    var $sidebar   = $("#sidebar"), 
        $window    = $(window),
        offset     = $sidebar.offset(),
        topPadding = 15;

    $window.scroll(function() {
        if ($window.scrollTop() > offset.top) {
            $sidebar.stop().animate({
                marginTop: $window.scrollTop() - offset.top + topPadding
            });
        } else {
            $sidebar.stop().animate({
                marginTop: 0
            });
        }
    });

});
```

**Credit [Css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/scrollfollow-sidebar/)**

The problem I am running into is that if the viewport height is too small it will hit the footer and start an infinite scroll.

You can recreate this by making the editor have low height and keep scrolling down.

Is there anyway to detect if the `sidebar` has hit the `footer` then disable scrolling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Is there anyway to detect if the sidebar has hit the footer then disable scrolling?" - So now your problem is to disable the scrolling of sidebar when it hits the bottom.

So, what i did is :

1. I got the entire height of the webpage and the height of the sidebar
2. Then i am creating a condition like this.

   ```
   var $sidebar = $("#sidebar"),
   $window = $(window),
   offset = $sidebar.offset(),
   topPadding = 15;

   var body = document.body,
       html = document.documentElement;

   var height = Math.max(body.scrollHeight, body.offsetHeight,
       html.clientHeight, html.scrollHeight, html.offsetHeight);

   $window.scroll(function() {
     if ($window.scrollTop() <= height - $("#sidebar").height()) {
       if ($window.scrollTop() > offset.top) {
           $sidebar.stop().animate({
               marginTop: $window.scrollTop() - offset.top + topPadding
           });
       } else {
           $sidebar.stop().animate({
               marginTop: 0
           });
       }
     }
   });
   ```

What this will do is It will check whether the scrollTop of window is less than ( entire webpage height - height of the sidebar) and if yes, the animation will happen and if no (if it hits the bottom of the page), the scrolling will be stopped.

Here is the [Link](https://jsfiddle.net/wbaymqkj/)

Hope this works for you :)

Answer (score 1):

You can add this in your css :

```
@media (max-height: 500px) {
  .sidebar-offcanvas {
      margin-top:0 !important;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep track of the footers initial position and then check if your sidebar has reached bottom here is the updated code

```
$(function() {

    var $sidebar   = $("#sidebar"), 
        $window    = $(window),
        offset     = $sidebar.offset(),
        topPadding = 60;

    var $footer = $('#footer');           
    var footeroffset = $footer.offset();   // here we get initial position of footer

    $window.scroll(function() {
       if ($window.scrollTop() > offset.top) {
           // we check if the sidebar is touching the footer
           if(footeroffset.top >($window.scrollTop() - offset.top + topPadding+$sidebar.height())){
               $sidebar.stop().animate({
                  marginTop: $window.scrollTop() - offset.top + topPadding
               });
           }
       } else {
           $sidebar.stop().animate({
               marginTop: 60
           });
       }
    });

 });
```

here is the [link](http://codepen.io/raj_2492/pen/bprYJb)